# Botones que no aparecen y se duplican

Tags: java, eclipse

Hola estoy intentando hacer un proyecto en java, en el cual intento crear unos botones encima de una imagen, usando un paintComponent en un JPanel, pero al agregar los botones al JPanel y ejecutar el programa, los botones no aparecen,(en un primer momento) pero al re-dimensionar la ventana, si aparecen, pero por alguna razón cada vez que re-dimensiono la ventana, la cantidad de botones se duplica,como si de alguna manera, hubiera un WindowsListener que cada vez que se re-dimensione la ventana,duplicara los frames del JPanel,mi pregunta es, como evito que los botones de dupliquen, y que mis botones aparezcan en el momento en que se abre el JPanel? aquí dejo el código de mi programa.

```
public class Numero_1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ventana Ventana = new ventana("ffff");
    Ventana.setVisible(true);
    Ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

}

class ventana extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

ventana(String clase) {
    super();
    Toolkit ventana = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension miventana = ventana.getScreenSize();
    int altura = miventana.height;
    int anchura = miventana.width;
    if (clase == "encriptador") {
        setBounds(anchura / 3, altura / 4, 1000, 667);
        encriptador Encriptador = new encriptador();
        add(Encriptador);

    } else if (clase == "desencriptador") {
        setBounds(anchura / 3, altura / 4, 1000, 600);
        desencriptador Desencriptador = new desencriptador();
        add(Desencriptador);

    } else {
        setBounds(anchura / 5, altura / 7, 1010, 580);
        inicio Inicio = new inicio();
        add(Inicio);
    }

    }

    }


class inicio extends JPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Image fondo;
private JButton encriptador;
private JButton desencriptador;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    File direccion = new File("lock_tech1010,580.jpg");
    try {
        BufferedImage boton = ImageIO.read(new 
File("botonvacioover350x100.png"));
        fondo = ImageIO.read(direccion);
        encriptador = new JButton("encriptador");
        desencriptador = new JButton("desencriptador");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    JPanel pantalla_izquierda = new JPanel();
    JPanel pantalla_derecha3 = new JPanel();
    JPanel pantalla_derecha3_1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel pantalla_derecha3_2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel pantalla_derecha3_3 = new JPanel();
    pantalla_derecha3_2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    pantalla_derecha3_3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    pantalla_derecha3.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    add(pantalla_izquierda);
    pantalla_derecha3.add(pantalla_derecha3_1);
    pantalla_derecha3.add(pantalla_derecha3_2);
    pantalla_derecha3.add(pantalla_derecha3_3);
    pantalla_derecha3_2.add(encriptador);
    pantalla_derecha3_3.add(desencriptador);
    pantalla_izquierda.setOpaque(false);
    pantalla_derecha3.setOpaque(false);
    pantalla_derecha3_1.setOpaque(false);
    pantalla_derecha3_2.setOpaque(false);
    pantalla_derecha3_3.setOpaque(false);
    g.drawImage(fondo, 0, 0, 1010, 580, null);
    add(pantalla_derecha3);

  }
```

Comment: Para que meterlo en un paintComponent si puede ir en el constructor? prueba en lucar de meterlo en un paintComponent meterlo en un constructor en la clase inicio y dices el resultado

Comment: vale @Sr1871 voy a intentar lo y te digo

Comment: @Sr1871 muchas gracias, saque del grapichs g los frames y lo puse en el constructor como dijiste y ya me va bien, gracias